# What is the Fastest Way to Select a Whole Table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am writing a app that reads a whole table, does some processing, then writes the resulting data to another table.  I am using the `SqlBulkCopy` class (.net version of "bcp in") which does the insert very fast.  But I cannot find any efficent way to select data in the first place.  there is not .net equivilent of "bcp out", which seems strange to me.

Currently I'm using `select * from table_name`.  For prespective it takes 2.5 seconds to select 6,000 rows ... and only 600ms to bulk insert the same number of rows.

I would expect that selecting data should always be faster than inserting.  **What is the fastest way to select all rows & columns from a table?**

---

Answers to qeustions:

- I timed my select to take 2.5 seconds 2 ways.  First was while running my application and running a sql trace.  second was running the same query in SSMS.  Both retured about the same result.
- I am reading data using SqlDataReader.
- No other applications are using this database.
- My current processing takes under 1 second, so 2+ second read time is relatively large.  But mostly I'm concerned(interested) in performance when scaling this up to 100,000 rows and millions of rows.
- Sql Server 08r2 and my application are both running on my dev machine.
- Some of the data processing is set based so I need to have the whole table in memory (to support much larger data sets, I know this step will probably need to be moved into SQL so I only need to operate per row in memory)

Here is my code:

```
DataTable staging = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection dwConn = (SqlConnection)SqlConnectionManager.Instance.GetDefaultConnection())
{
    dwConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = dwConn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from staging_table";

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    staging.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: How much time does your processing take?

Comment: How are you measuring this 2.5 seconds? In SSMS or in your application? If the former what if you turn on the option "Discard Results After Execution" to eliminate SSMS processing time. If the latter How does your application retrieve the rows - Are you using a data reader for example? What does your code look like?

Comment: Whilst you are reading from this table, do any other applications write to the table? If so, you might want to try using the "WITH (NOLOCK)" option.

Comment: Not necessarily.  When reading you have to find the data on disk, but when writing you are just writing out to the specified location.  You could try creating a new index that you rebuild/reorganize regularly so that reads are more efficient.

Comment: Have you to tried System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect?

Comment: I think you need to provide some details on how you were timing this.  Are you using a DataAdapter or a DataReader?  How are you managing your connection?  Probably a few other questions, too.  If you could post your timing code, that would be helpful.

Comment: @juharr: CommandType.TableDirect is not supported by sql server.  I was surprised to learn this.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8a69e0c7-d839-450f-85bf-1942858766ba

Comment: Is the server you're running the query on your local network? 2.5 seconds to select 6000 rows seems kind of slow, unless the server is at a remote site and you're accessing it over the internet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`select * from table_name` **is** the simplest, easiest and fastest way to read a whole table.

Let me explain why your results lead to wrong conclusions.

1. Copying a whole table is an optimized operation that merely requires *cloning* the old binary data into the new one (at most you can perform a file copy operation, according to storage mechanism).
2. **Writing is buffered**. DBMS says the record was written but it's actually not yet done, unless you work with transactions. Disk operations are generally delayed.
3. Querying a table also requires (unlike cloning) adapting data from the binary-stored layout/format to a driver-dependant format that is ultimately readable by your client. This takes time.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your hardware, but it is likely that your network is the bottleneck here.

Apart from limiting your query to just read the columns you'd actually be using, doing a select is as fast as it will get. There is caching involved here, when you execute it twice in a row, the second time shoud be much faster because the data is cached in memory. execute `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` to check the effect of caching.

If you want to do it as fast as possible try to implement the code that does the processing in T-SQL, that way it could operate directly on the data right there on the server.

Another good tip for speed tuning is have the table that is being read on one disk (look at filegroups) and the table that is written to on another disk. That way one disk can do a continuous read and the other a continuous write. If both operations happen on the same disk the heads of the disk keep going back and forth what seriously downgrades performance.

If the logic your writing cannot be doen it T-SQL you could also have a look at SQL CLR.

Another tip: when you do select * from table, use a datareader if possible. That way you don't materialize the whole thing in memory first.

GJ

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea generally to include the column names in the select list, but with today's RDBMS's, it won't make much difference. You will only see difference in this regard if you limit the columns selected. Generally speaking it is good practice to include column names. But to answer it seems a select is indeed slower than inserting in the scenario you describe
and yes a `select * from table_name` is indeed the fastest way to read all rows and cols from a table

Comment: +1 because this *IS* helpful and includes a good point I agree with that isn't in the other answer.